# Thiele's Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential, actuarial-science

For those of you who are familiar with Thiele's differential equation in life insurance, i would like to ask of you to explain to me what exactly it tells us. It is not a very hard equation to understand and calculate, but what does it actuall tell us? what do we use it for when it comes to life insurance mathematics.

Thank you

Comment: see here http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03461238.1990.10413874 i hope this will help you